# Graphing matplotlib with Python code in a R Markdown document

Tags: matplotlib, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to use Python matplotlib code to draw graph in RStudio?

e.g. below Python matplotlib code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 256
X = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n,endpoint=True)
Y = np.sin(2*X)

plt.plot (X, Y+1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
plt.plot (X, Y-1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
plt.show()
```

Output graph will be:

[image]

Then I need to write a R Markdown to include these code and generate graph automatically after knitting the markdown.

Comment: R can do it easy! why need to use python!

Comment: @lucky1928 It's just a example, python can do many other things which not proper for R. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible solution is save the plot as a image, then load the file to markdown.

````
### Call python code sample
```{r,engine='python'}
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 256
X = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n,endpoint=True)
Y = np.sin(2*X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 )
ax.plot (X, Y+1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
ax.plot (X, Y-1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
#plt.show()
fig.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
print "finished"
```
Output image:
![output](foo.png)

#### The End
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: I had a go today at trying to use hooks in knitr to make this solution more automatic, but the issue was that the hooks are written in R, so don't seem to have any access to the python code. Maybe there's a way to write out some python code at the end though.

Comment: Now, anno 2018, you can insert Python code in Rmarkdown. To plot something with matplotlib you simply need to add `plt.show`.

Answer (score 18):

1. install.packages('devtools') first, get install_github function
2. install_github("rstudio/reticulate") install the dev version of reticulate
3. in r markdown doc, use code below to enable the function.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}  
library(knitr)  
library(reticulate)  
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)  
```
````

Try it , you will get what you want and don't need to save any image.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: The code is inside the R Markdown document, as the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `reticulate`, but most time in trying to follow a tutorial in doing that you may encounter some technicalities that weren't sufficiently explained.

My answer is a little late but I hope it's a thorough walkthrough of doing it the right way - not rendering it and then loading it as a png but have the python code executed more "natively".

### Step 1: Configure Python from RStudio

You want to insert an R chunk, and run the following code to configure the path to the version of Python you want to use. The default `python` that comes shipped with most OS is usually the outdated python 2 and is not where you install your packages. That is the reason why it's important to do this, to make sure Rstudio will use the specified python instance where your `matplotlib` library (and the other libraries you will be using for that project) can be found:

```
library(reticulate)
# change the following to point to the desired path on your system
use_python('/Users/Samuel/anaconda3/bin/python')
# prints the python configuration
py_config()
```

You should expect to see that your session is configured with the settings you specified:

```
python:         /Users/Samuel/anaconda3/bin/python
libpython:      /Users/Samuel/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib
pythonhome:     /Users/Samuel/anaconda3:/Users/Samuel/anaconda3
version:        3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
numpy:          /Users/Samuel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.15.2

python versions found: 
 /Users/Samuel/anaconda3/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python
 /usr/local/bin/python3
 /Users/Samuel/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/bin/python
```

### Step 2: The familiar `plt.show`

Add a Python chunk (not R!) in your R Markdown document (see attached screenshot) and you can now write native Python code. This means that the familiar `plt.show()` and `plt.imshow()` will work without any extra work. It will be rendered and can be compiled into HTML / PDF using `knitr`.

This will work:

```
plt.imshow(my_image, cmap='gray')
```

Or a more elaborated example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = '/Users/Samuel/Datasets/PetImages'
CATEGORIES = ['Dog', 'Cat']

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) # path to cat or dog dir
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
        break
    break
```

Output:
[image]

### Step 3: Knit to HTML / PDF / Word etc

Proceed to knit as usual. The end product is a beautifully formatted document done in Python code using R Markdown. RStudio has come a long way and I'm surprised the level of support it has for Python code isn't more known so hoping anyone that stumbled upon this answer will find it informative and learned something new.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with reticulate and R Markdown and you should specify your virtual environment. For example my R Markdown starts as follows:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, cache.lazy = FALSE)
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv('pytorch') ## yes, you can run pytorch and tensor flow too
```

Then you can work in either language. So, for plotting with matplotlib, I have found that you need the PyQt5 module to make it all run smoothly. The following makes a nice plot inside R Markdown - it's a separate chunk.

```
{python plot}
import PyQt5
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

data = pd.read_csv('Subscriptions.csv',index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# make the nice plot
# set the figure size
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))

# the series
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(data.index.values, data.Opens, color = 'green', label = 'Opens')

# plot the legend for the first plot
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = 14)

plt.ylabel('Opens', fontsize=16)

# Hide the top x axis
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

#######  NOW PLOT THE OTHER SERIES ON A SINGLE PLOT

# plot 212 is the MI series

# plot series
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(data.index.values, data.Joiners, color = 'orange', label = 'Joiners')

# plot the legend for the second plot
ax2.legend(loc = 'upper right', fontsize = 14)

# set the fontsize for the bottom plot
plt.ylabel('Joiners', fontsize=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You get the following from this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation points to add a comment, but Bryan's answer above was the only one to work for me. Adding `plt.tight_layout()` made the difference. I added that line to the following simple code and the plot displayed.

```
{python evaluate}

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'gray')
plt.plot(X_train, regresssion_model_sklearn.predict(X_train), color = 'red')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.xlabel('Number of Years of Experience')
plt.title('Salary vs. Years of Experience')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31389506)