# %matplotlib inline in Rmarkdown /R notebooks

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, r-markdown

**Context:** I am doing a bit of comparison between Jupyter Notebooks and R Notebooks. One thing I like about R notebooks is you can vary language between cells. I am testing this with the following published notebook https://bitaesthetics.com/posts/fractal-generation-with-l-systems.html

**Problem:** Drawing python results inline does not seem to work. I can call `plt.show()`, and have the graph pop up, but  `%matplotlib inline` produces the following error:

```
File "/var/folders/30/dl1nh_s15mq9j9b0469q_vvh0000gn/T/RtmpjAYRiE/chunk-code22c26a73f799.", line 1
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Reproducible Example:**

````
```{python}
    %matplotlib inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('bmh')  # Use some nicer default colors
    plt.plot(
        [0, 1, 2],  # X-values
        [0, 1, 0]   # Y-values
    )
    # The next two lines add labels to the axes.
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y');
```
````

Anyone have any experience with this? I checked the Rstudio help page and GitHub and found that they're working on a new package, reticulate, https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/pull/107#issuecomment-359944469, rather than offering a lot of support for native python in R markdown.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `%matplotlib inline` is not native python. In python a `%` is a modulo operator or a string formatter. The `%magic_command` comes from `IPython`, so what would be needed is to integrate `IPython` into the notebook. Not sure if that is even possible by design or desirable though.

Comment: Ah thank you! So I wonder still how to get inline matplotlib results in an R notebook. Maybe not worth investing in though.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437028/graphing-matplotlib-with-python-code-in-a-r-markdown-document seems matplotlib plot work for others.