# Printing image in r-markdown using matplotlib and python code

Tags: python, r, r-markdown

I am trying to run the python code using the R-Markdown file (RMarkdown to pdf).

What I achieved till now -
1- I am able to configure my python engine using knitr and reticulate library
2- I am able to execute my python codes.

What I tried -
1- I tried all the methods which are discussed in this forum, but nothing is working out.
2- I also tried to save the image,([as one of the posts here suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437028/graphing-matplotlib-with-python-code-in-a-r-markdown-document)), but that also is not working.
My problem -

1- When I am trying to plot a graph using matlplotlib and command plt.imshow() and plt.show(), it's not printing the image in the output. Rather it's showing the image in a separate window. You can see my results in the attached image.

[Result_of_my_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpJs.png)

Here is my code

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```

```{python}


import numpy as np
import os
import torch
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('D:\\1st year\\Python codes\\CIFR Analysis\\self contained analysis')
print(os.getcwd())
train_mnist = dsets.MNIST("../data", train=True)
test_mnist = dsets.MNIST("../data", train= False)
print(len(train_mnist))

#print(train_mnist[0][0])
plt.imshow(train_mnist[0][0], cmap="gray")
#plt.savefig("trainzero.png")

plt.show()

```
````

Kindly, help me to fix this issue, as I want to compile my python codes using the R markdown file.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with R Markdown, you have to do some things a little differently.  In the following, I have a dataframe with two series created by concatenating them.  The original plotting code in the Jupyter Notebook is as follows and just printed out the series.

```
# make a plot of model fit
train.plot(figsize=(16,8), legend=True)
backtest.plot(legend=True);
```

[image]

However, it does not work with way with R Markdown.  Then with plotting, you always have to assign them, and with the code below, you get the same plot.

```
dfreg = pd.concat([reg, backtest], axis = 1)

ax = dfreg.plot(figsize=(16,8), legend = True)
ax1 = predictions.plot(legend=True)
plt.show()
```

This is common with other plotting functions like `plot_acf()` too.